# How to disable cut, copy and paste option to MTextBox and MPasswordTextBox in MGWt

Tags: ios, cordova, copy, mgwt

I developed an mgwt,gwt-phonegap app and I installed it in ios device. I want to disable the cut ,copy and paste options to my text fields.

Is there any chance to do it through css? if not please provide me solution to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This disable the copy / paste for everything except input :

```
   *{
        -webkit-touch-callout: none;
        -webkit-user-select:none;
    }
    input {
        -webkit-touch-callout: auto !important;
        -webkit-user-select: auto !important;
    }
```

You can use it to target your text fields only.